# How to check for a process in mac os using coca

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to check if this process "screencapture" is running with my app, how to check for it with cocoa

Answer (score 0):

NSRunningApplication

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication/1530730-runningapplicationwithprocesside

_
_
_
_
_
_
_

Comment: In terms of Cocoa `screencapture` is not an application

Comment: It is. The "screencapture" process is the app bundle "/System/Library/CoreServices/screencaptureui.app" and the identifier is com.apple.screencaptureui

Comment: The question is about `screencapture` so I am talking about `/usr/sbin/screencapture` which is a CLI

Comment: "screencapture" is ambiguous. The process name when the user takes a screenshot by pressing the keyboard shortcuts, is "screencapture". You can see this in Activity Monitor. That process is as I described. The CLI tool does not have an embedded Info.plist etc and in that case you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
let availableApps = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.your.bundleid")
if availableApps.count > 0  {
    print("Process is running")
}
else {
    print("Process is running")
}
```

Comment: In terms of Cocoa `screencapture` is not an application

Comment: if its a process with valid bundleid, you can use the above

Comment: OK, what is the bundle identifier of `screencapture`?

Comment: I don't follow your question. What exactly is the "screencapture" you are talking about?

Comment: The *process "screencapture"* what the question is about.

Comment: If it is a process, you should be able to figure out the bundleid of it. You can google some of these things. The answers are easily available. If it is a legit process (something you can see in Activity Monitor), then you can use 
osascript -e 'id of app "ProcessName"'

Comment: No, a process doesn't have necessarily a bundle identifier, only application bundles have one. `screencapture` is not an application bundle, it's a command line interface which doesn't have a bundle identifier and therefore it can't be a `NSRunningApplication`.

Comment: @vadian That's wrong in several ways. A) non-bundle processes can absolutely have a bundle identifier. The Info.plist is embedded in the executable itself. B) The "screencapture" process is the app bundle "/System/Library/CoreServices/screencaptureui.app"  C) the identifier is com.apple.screencaptureui   The answer I gave is correct.